# numpy slice to return last two dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Basically I'm looking for a function or syntax that will allow me to get the first 'slice' of the last two dimensions of a n dimensional numpy array with an arbitrary number of dimensions.

I can do this but it's too ugly to live with, and what if someone sends a 6d array in?  There must be a numpy function like the ellipse that expands to 0,0,0,... instead of :,:,:,...

```
data_2d = np.ones(5**2).reshape(5,5)
data_3d = np.ones(5**3).reshape(5,5,5)
data_4d = np.ones(5**4).reshape(5,5,5,5)

def get_last2d(data):
    if data.ndim == 2:
        return data[:]
    if data.ndim == 3:
        return data[0, :]
    if data.ndim == 4:
        return data[0, 0, :]

np.array_equal(get_last2d(data_3d), get_last2d(data_4d))
```

Thanks,
Colin

Comment: Why do you want to get the last two dimensions only of the zeroth entry? Is there a valid use case for that? I came here looking for a good way to flatten an array into a format that keeps the last two dimensions, which I think is a very valid use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this,

```
def get_last2d(data):
    if data.ndim <= 2:
        return data
    slc = [0] * (data.ndim - 2)
    slc += [slice(None), slice(None)]
    return data[slc]
```

Comment: That totally works!  I haven't seen the slice(None) syntax before nor the concept of storing my slice indexes in a list.

Comment: Great! Yes, both concepts are useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_last_2d(x):
    m,n = x.shape[-2:]
    return x.flat[:m*n].reshape(m,n)
```

This works because flattening an array returns entries in order of the fasted-varying index, and for C-style indexing, the last indices vary the fastest. So the first m*n entries of the flattened array are what you want.